# 'FFMPEG: moov atom not found' on my dash cam videos

Tags: ffmpeg, mp4

I have several dash cam videos. The first 3 of them are opened through the VLC. Other files - no

When trying to open them ffmpeg:

```
ffmpeg version 4.4.2-0ubuntu0.22.04.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2021 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 11 (Ubuntu 11.2.0-19ubuntu1)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version=0ubuntu0.22.04.1 --toolchain=hardened --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --incdir=/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu --arch=amd64 --enable-gpl --disable-stripping --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libaom --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libcodec2 --enable-libdav1d --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libjack --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libmysofa --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librabbitmq --enable-librubberband --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libsrt --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzimg --enable-libzmq --enable-libzvbi --enable-lv2 --enable-omx --enable-openal --enable-opencl --enable-opengl --enable-sdl2 --enable-pocketsphinx --enable-librsvg --enable-libmfx --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libdrm --enable-libiec61883 --enable-chromaprint --enable-frei0r --enable-libx264 --enable-shared
  libavutil      56. 70.100 / 56. 70.100
  libavcodec     58.134.100 / 58.134.100
  libavformat    58. 76.100 / 58. 76.100
  libavdevice    58. 13.100 / 58. 13.100
  libavfilter     7.110.100 /  7.110.100
  libswscale      5.  9.100 /  5.  9.100
  libswresample   3.  9.100 /  3.  9.100
  libpostproc    55.  9.100 / 55.  9.100
Splitting the commandline.
Reading option '-i' ... matched as input url with argument '/home/b/Downloads/Normal/FILE20231122-184948-000049.MP4'.
Reading option '-loglevel' ... matched as option 'loglevel' (set logging level) with argument '48'.
Finished splitting the commandline.
Parsing a group of options: global .
Applying option loglevel (set logging level) with argument 48.
Successfully parsed a group of options.
Parsing a group of options: input url /home/b/Downloads/Normal/FILE20231122-184948-000049.MP4.
Successfully parsed a group of options.
Opening an input file: /home/b/Downloads/Normal/FILE20231122-184948-000049.MP4.
[NULL @ 0x55fddf21a5c0] Opening '/home/b/Downloads/Normal/FILE20231122-184948-000049.MP4' for reading
[file @ 0x55fddf21b240] Setting default whitelist 'file,crypto,data'
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x55fddf21a5c0] Format mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 detected only with low score of 1, misdetection possible!
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x55fddf21a5c0] moov atom not found
[AVIOContext @ 0x55fddf223640] Statistics: 1081344 bytes read, 3 seeks
/home/b/Downloads/Normal/FILE20231122-184948-000049.MP4: Invalid data found when processing input
```

I tried https://github.com/ponchio/untrunc because I have the "correct" videos, but it didn't work, I just started getting another error:

```
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x55936f11b5c0] stream 0, contradictionary STSC and STCO
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x55936f11b5c0] error reading header
```

I tried different online video recovery services - it didn’t help.

Is it possible to restore the video? (not necessarily with audio track)
Considering that I have working videos from the same DVR